# How to add a title with a transparent background in iMovie?

Tags: imovie

I'm using iMovie 10.0.8 and like to display some text with a transparent background over the clip. Can this somehow be done?
The titles view only lists titles on a black, white and color bar, but color bar does not allow to set an alpha value for the background...
Any ideas how text with transparent background can be added to a clip are welcome,
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

drag the title over the clip you want to lay it over in the title track. the background in the title view is already transparent, defaulting to black if you do not lay it over a clip.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like photoshop to make some text with a transparent background

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Create a transparent png with black background in photoshop

[image: Image with opacity 80]

Step 2: Insert the image as picture in picture

[image: Add transparent image in imovie]

follow instructions from here https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22931?locale=en_US

Step 3: Position the picture behind the title